# show that (A,B,C,D) isn't independent , (A,B,C) is independent

Tags: probability

flipping 3 coins. A={first coin head}, B={second coin head}, C={third coin head}, D={the total number of heads is odd}

show that
(A,B,C,D) isn't independent , (A,B,C) is independent

I have to show it with the definition of independence: A and B are independent if: P(A∩B)=P(A)* P(B)

I never did a independence proof before so can please someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to show it with the definition of independence: A and B are independent if: P(A∩B)=P(A)* P(B)
>
> I never did a independence proof before so can please someone help me?

Just do what you were told:  Evaluate the probabilities of the marginals and the conjunctions.

If the four events are mutually independent, then $\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C\cap D)=\mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(B)\,\mathsf P(C)\,\mathsf P(D)$ . So is this true?

$A\cap B\cap C\cap D$ is the event that the three coins coins show heads and the count of heads is odd.  What is the probability for this event?

What are the marginal probabilities for the individual events?

---

Likewise if the first three events are mutually independent, then $\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C)=\mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(B)\,\mathsf P(C)$ . So is this true?

So...

Comment: ok then:P(A∩B∩C)=1/6, P(A)*P(B)*P(C)=1/6 ->independent,   P(A∩B∩C∩D)=1/6, P(A)*P(B)*P(C)*P(D)=1/2*1/2*1/2*2/3=1/9  so dependent. is it right?

Comment: $\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C) = 1/2^3 =1/8$ because of the $2^3$ equally possible outcomes of the coin flips, there is only one outcome in the favoured event of all three coins showing heads. *et cetera*.

Comment: oh yes youre right stupid calculation error. then P(A∩B∩C)=1/8, P(A)*P(B)*P(C)=1/8 ->independent, P(A∩B∩C∩D)=1/8, P(A)*P(B)*P(C)*P(D)=1/8*1/2=1/16 so dependent. is it now correct?

Comment: @thombirdy Indeed.

Comment: Ok thank you so muchl!!